# Push git alias to remote repo

Tags: git

Is it possible to push a git alias to a git repo so everyone that clones that repo can use that alias?

Example:

```
git config alias.st "status -s"
git push
```

Does the alias gets pushed?

PD: What I want to achieve is something to develop a several steps tutorial, so whenever I do "next" or "git next" it switches to the branch of the next level.

Comment: An alias is local to your config (at the system level, user level, or repo level), for good reasons (security, in particular). You cannot push an alias to a remote. However, you can always push a commit that contains a text file with the definition of your alias in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias is part of your local (system-level, user-level, or repo-level) config.
Because you cannot share your local config via `git push`, you cannot push an alias to a remote.

There is a good security reason for such a restriction: imagine if aliases got copied to the local config of anyone who cloned your repo and you had defined an alias equivalent to `sudo rm -rf /`, encouraging people to use it. Mayhem would ensue...

What you can always do, however, if you want to share the definition of your alias with other people, is to push a commit that contains a text file with the definition of your alias in it.